# How to extend CalendarView to allow selection of multiple dates?

Tags: android, calendarview

I want to show a user with a calendar where multiple dates are selected.

While this could be easily achieved using [Material Calendar View](https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview) but I prefer not to use dependency for this simple task.

How could I achieve this by extending android `CalendarView`?

Please help

Comment: You can use the [MaterialDatePicker](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Picker.md) There is a [SingleDateSelector](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/SingleDateSelector.java). You can extends the class for a MultipleDateSelector

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti can you please write an answer using MaterialDatePicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would refer you to a comment on [How to highlight multiple dates in Android CalendarView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41837100/how-to-highlight-multiple-dates-in-android-calendarview).

It basically says CalendarView does not support this, and that the point of CalendarView is to allow the user to choose a date.

Good luck!

Comment: I wonder how libs achieve this? Do they implement calendar from scratch?

Comment: I have done it once or twice before so i would imagine so, and by looking in the lib you linked they are doing it from scratch.